# How to queue events in my Swift game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, grand-central-dispatch

I spent some time looking into various approaches for queuing and even read this http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1 which was helpful, but I feel as the more I read into GCD, the more confused and unsure I become of myself about the right approach. Could someone give me a recommendation?

My goal is this: I'm making a game where a player can lose health due to some game event. The player has a health bar (hearts) at the top, and each time they get hit, I animate a heart to fly upwards over a .1 time interval. The reason i'm exploring a queue of some sort is the player can lose health so rapidly in some cases that the events fire faster than the animation. As a result, it sometimes "skips" hearts because it can't keep up with the health loss. This is only on some levels where the damage taken is higher than usual. Even without the animation it still happens occasionally although I think a tad bit less.

So I was thinking what I could do is queue up each health loss event, this way it will force the events to go in order, but I wasn't successful (it still went super fast and skipped hearts, removing the 10th heart, the 8th heart, and the 5th, then it said game over. I want to slow it down and remove the hearts in order so you see them vanishing).

This was the code I attempted:

```
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            heartToRemove!.runAction(
                SKAction.sequence([SKAction.moveByX(0, y:50, duration:0.1),
                    SKAction.runBlock
                    {
                        heartToRemove!.removeFromParent()
                        self.hearts.removeLast()
                    }]))
                })
```

So the idea is to run 3 actions on a queue:
first, move the heart up. next, remove visually from the parent (so it vanishes off the game not just positioned above), and finally remove it from the array of SKNodes (the hearts) so that the next time a heart is removed, it goes to the next one in line not the same one if that makes sense.

I also tried dispatch_sync but that just froze my game so I assume that is wrong. Any other recommendations?

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the number of items in your hearths array to offset the animation times

something like :

```
    let wait   = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1 * NSTimeInterval(hearts.count-1))
    let move   = SKAction.moveByX(0, y:50, duration:0.1)
    let remove = SKAction.runBlock()
                 {
                    heartToRemove!.removeFromParent()
                    self.hearts.removeLast()
                 }        
    heartToRemove!.runAction(SKAction.sequence([ wait, move, remove ]))
```

Then you won't have to worry about queueing the actions.